# Send a file to Windows server directory in Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have a interface which is a database to file Interface.

After processing the records, I put the generated file on a Unix directory path. My requirement is to send the output file to a Windows Server directory instead of Unix in Oracle Data Integrator.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are (2) options:

1. After generating the file on the ODI/Unix server, use an `[OdiFtpPut]` step to FTP the file to the Windows server
2. Write a Java app that will reside on the ODI/Unix server, after generating the file, use a an OS Command step to invoke the Java app (using parameters) to perform the file move or FTP